# Role based login in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a page in php which allows the users to update,create and delete the list. There are two types of users, admin and student. I want to allow the students only to view the list and allow the admin to perform other operation. I have created the table to view the actions. How can I separate it for different users? I cannot redirect the users based upon their role because user needs to click button to perform action.

```
    <?php
    include 'Database.php';
        $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM student");
        while ($res=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $res['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $res['Username']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $res['Email']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $res['Course']; ?></td>
                <td> <button class="w3-btn w3-red"> <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $res['id']; ?>"> Delete </a>  </button>
                 <button class="w3-btn w3-blue"> <a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $res['id']; ?>"> Update </a> </button> </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Couldn't you assign a session id to any admin users? check that at the form section and if their id is equal to an admin id number then display the delete options?

Comment: *"I cannot redirect the users based upon their role"* - I see no redirection here.

Comment: Well, how do you define which user is which type?  Put that logic in an `if` statement.  For one type of user, do one thing.  For the other type, do another thing.

Comment: Firstly determine what type of user is using the system. We don't know how your login system works so we can't give specific advice about that. Once you've figured that out, put the user's type value into a variable. Use that variable in some `if` statements to decide what to display. Then in the delete.php and update.php scripts, do the same test before actually performing any changes to the database, to check that a non-admin user has not managed to discover the URL and browse to it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first create a table for users:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_role` ENUM('admin', 'student') NOT NULL DEFAULT `student`,
  `user_registered` datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `user_email` (`user_email`)
);
```

Then the login page:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass  = $_POST['pass'];

    ...

    // Save user into $_SESSION
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
}
```

View users page:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $res['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $res['Username']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $res['Email']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $res['Course']; ?></td>
    <td>
    <?php if($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 'admin'): ?>
        <button class="w3-btn w3-red"><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $res['id']; ?>">Delete</a></button>
        <button class="w3-btn w3-blue"><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $res['id']; ?>">Update</a></button>
    <?php elseif($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 'student'): ?>
        ...
    <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

On update & delete page add this code:

```
if($_SESSION['user']['role'] != 'admin'){
    die("You're not allowed to do this action!");
}
```